# ¿Cómo contar los elementos de una columna solo si se cumple una condición en otra? R

Tags: r

quería saber cómo puedo hacer para contar los elementos de una columna, solo si se cumple cierta condición en otra. En mi caso, tengo una columna con estado civil, y otra con el nivel de autoestima, y quiero saber el nivel de autoestima de las personas solteras. ¿Qué función debería utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso que la variable autoestima es categórica, puedes utilizar el mismo código, pero tienes que actualizar los parámetros de la función `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

## Create a data frame (tibble)
DF <- tibble(`Estado Civil` = rep(c("soltero", "casado"), 5)[-10],
             `Nivel de Autoestima` = rep(c("alta", "media","baja"), 3))

DF

  `Estado Civil` `Nivel de Autoestima`
  <chr>          <chr>                
1 soltero        alta                 
2 casado         media                
3 soltero        baja                 
4 casado         alta                 
5 soltero        media                
6 casado         baja                 
7 soltero        alta                 
8 casado         media                
9 soltero        baja
```

**Resultado:**

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(`Estado Civil`,`Nivel de Autoestima`) %>% 
  summarize(
    num_elementos = n()
  )

  `Estado Civil` `Nivel de Autoestima` num_elementos
  <chr>          <chr>                         <int>
1 casado         alta                              1
2 casado         baja                              1
3 casado         media                             2
4 soltero        alta                              2
5 soltero        baja                              2
6 soltero        media                             1
```

De este modo, puedes contar la frecuencia del número de elementos basados primero en función del estado civil, y luego por el nivel de autoestima.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto puede ser un ejemplo de lo que necesitas. Para esto, necesitas las funciones `filter` y `group_by` del paquete `dplyr`.

Primero tienes que filtar tu dataframe con la variable de interes, en este caso nivel de autoestima, y luego agrupar los resultados segun estado civil y generar un resumen de los valores que buscas, por ejemplo en este caso el promedio del nivel de autoestima de cada estado civil, y el numero de elementos que cada estado civil tiene.

```
library(dplyr)

## Create a data frame (tibble)
DF <- tibble(`Estado Civil` = rep(c("soltero", "casado"), 5)[-10],
             `Nivel de Autoestima` = rep(c(1, 10, 1), 3))

DF

  `Estado Civil` `Nivel de Autoestima`
  <chr>                          <dbl>
1 soltero                            1
2 casado                            10
3 soltero                            1
4 casado                             1
5 soltero                           10
6 casado                             1
7 soltero                            1
8 casado                            10
9 soltero                            1
```

**Resultado:**

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(`Estado Civil`) %>% 
  summarize(
    nivel_autoestima_promedio = mean(`Nivel de Autoestima`),
    num_elementos = n()
  )


  `Estado Civil` nivel_autoestima_promedio num_elementos
  <chr>                              <dbl>         <int>
1 casado                               5.5             4
2 soltero                              2.8             5
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Quisiera saber qué puedo hacer en el caso de que la variable de autoestima sea categórica, no numérica... ya que tengo autoestima alta, media y baja. Si me pudieras ayudar te lo agradecería demasiado.